# How do I alternate between local repos once I clone them from github?

Tags: github

My title basically says it all.  I have 2 different repos that I would like to work on, I cloned both of them through Terminal, but I can't figure out how to switch back and forth between them.  And I don't want to commit a file to the wrong repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to commit a file to the wrong repo.

You won't since the repos have been cloned to two different local folders.
If the file is in one of those folders, and `git add` and `git commit` will be done in the right local repo.
So to switch from one to the other, simple change your current path to the right folder.

Comment: And how would I go about changing the path?

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been killing me.  And sorry for the incorrect formatting on the original post.